# change of encoding shows Weird symbols

Tags: html, css, encoding

The unknown symbols after writing some HTML CSS appear in code how and from where they come from

```
<table width="96%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="39%" style="border:1px solid red"></td>
                <td width="60%" valign="center" style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; border:1px dashed black; letter-spacing:-0.5px; line-height:100%;"><h4>Personal message</h4></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Do not ask questions why to use tables in html or inner styling 
the look above is what you see if you write it in Encoding UTF-8
after switching the Encoding to ANSI some characters appear in the code

```
<table width="96%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="39%" style="border:1px solid red"></td>
                <td width="60%" valign="center" style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bold; border:1px dashed black; letter-spacing:-0.5px; line-height:100%;">ā€‹<h4>Personal message</h4>ā€‹</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

What I would like to know is why it is happening and how to avoid it?

ā€‹

UPDATE: - What Program did I use?
This was created using Notepad++ only with encoding UTF-8 and only after changing to ANSI it showed that there are some unknown characters

Comment: If you use some Web Server, check parameter of encoding and change it to UTF-8. it's can solve the problem

Comment: yes but why such things come a cross miss spelling something? deleting cutting copy paste? i want to avoid this as much as possible

Comment: yes, encoding problems can be embarrassing. but is so stange.
If you use an IDE like eclipse of Netbeans try to check encoding of the HTML editor file.

Comment: We cannot know what you have done in an unspecified program in an unspecified manner to produce a string of characters, or some byte sequence that might be interpreted as a string when making a wild and probably wrong guess of the encoding.

Comment: Could it appear if I change Programming languages like from HTML to CSS in NotePad++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this strings in my Notepad++ and it seems you have a UTF-8 space in the source code.
If you check this table here: 
http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal

First entries are spaces and my Notepad++ gave me that your chars are:
ax80x8B (what matches with the table in the link above).

Probably you created the source-code in a utf-8 text editor. 
Just open the file in an editor capable of converting between UTF-8 ASCII and save in the correct format.

In your case, convert in the editor to ascii, delete the invalid chars, save it making sure it's ascii and only after that upload to your server. :)

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Unfortunately I'm rusty in linux and don't remember any editor capable of doing this but I'm sure there is one.